# I am unable to enforce workflow to stop after first task rejected

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, status

How to get workflow task status weather that task is approved or rejected.

Ex: I made a workflow and multiple tasks. I am unable to enforce workflow to stop after first task rejected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SharePoint 2013 Designer Workflow, it is very easy.

> Assign a task activity will have an outcome variable
>   [image]
>
> Put a if condition under transition and check for the task outcome.
>
> End workflow if task is rejected.
>
> Also the task should have been configured to wait for completion.

Ref. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj614606.aspx